# AWS S3 changes to bucket / prefix using aws-sdk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I can see there is a way to change the prefix for the collection by using:

```
objects = collection.with_prefix('a/').with_prefix('b/', :replace)
objects.prefix #=> 'b/'
```

Question: How do I save this change?

http://rubydoc.info/github/amazonwebservices/aws-sdk-for-ruby/master/AWS/S3/ObjectCollection:with_prefix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can move objects between "folders" in S3 by using the AWS::S3::S3Object#move_to method.

```
bucket.objects.with_prefix('a/').each do |obj|
  obj.move_to(obj.key.sub(/^a/, 'b'))
end
```

The :replace and :append arguments on AWS::S3::ObjectCollection#with_prefix control the behavior of how #with_prefix builds the prefix it would use to filter enumerated objects when chained.  An example usage of :append might look like:

```
# enumerates objects inside folder1 / folder2
bucket.objects.with_prefix(folder1).with_prefix(folder2, :append).each do |obj|
end
```

Of course, you could accomplish this by just joining the prefixes in a single call to #with_prefix:

```
# enumerate objects with the prefix 'abc/xyz/'
folder1 = 'abc/'
folder2 = 'xyz/'
bucket.objects.with_prefix("#{folder1}#{folder2}").each do |object|
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Ignore my answer, If I am not getting your point?

You want to change prefix of the object exist in the s3 bucket.
It can only be possible if you copy the object with new prefix and then delete the older one.